# Different components in same column in datatable in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf

Is it possible to have different types of components in a single column in a data table using JSF 2.0?

My requirement is that based on the `label` column value, the `value` column will have an input text or select list accordingly.

Currently I'm trying to do this via a backing bean. I have the `label`, `value` and `type of component` (e.g. "selectlist") in an `arraylist`.

When I'm iterating this list in a data table, how do I check the type and depending on the outcome create either an input or select list?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `rendered` attribute with a test that uses whatever it is you use to distinguish between an input and a select list.

E.g.

```xml
<h:dataTable value="#{yourBacking.yourList} var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" rendered="#{item.type == 'input'}" />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.value}" rendered="#{item.type == 'selectlist'}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{item.values}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```